# Making my website support emoji one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, unicode, emoji

So, i tried adding [emoji one](http://emojione.com/developers) support in my website by adding the script and css they provided.

i tried as it is in the [demo](http://git.emojione.com/demos/1.5.2/jsunicodetoimage.html) but no result.

http://jsfiddle.net/v7e2krjr/6/

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.5.2/lib/js/emojione.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.5.2/assets/css/emojione.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget `=` after class in your html

http://jsfiddle.net/v7e2krjr/3/

Comment: @Vizz what's wrong now? Your fiddle is working.

Comment: i am trying something else on this concept. http://jsfiddle.net/v7e2krjr/6/

Comment: You didn't call the function and you didn't have elements with specifed ids http://jsfiddle.net/v7e2krjr/7/

Comment: thanks. but i need a javascript code that works without using ids to convert into emojis . http://jsfiddle.net/v7e2krjr/10/

Comment: @Vizz just use `document.body` instead of `getElementById`. http://jsfiddle.net/v7e2krjr/11/